# Images not updating in pygame

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a dice game for my computing coursework and i am using python to do this. The game is yahtzee and so I have loaded in 6 images of dice to represent the faces of the dice. The theory is that a random number between 1 and 6 is generated and then depending on what the number is a different dice image is loaded in. I put the dice roll inside a function and it is called whenever i press the spacebar. Although a random number is being generated and printed in the shell none of the dice images are updating.

```
            import pygame, random
            pygame.init()
            FPS = 30
            fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
            Display_Height = 500
            Display_Width = 750
            GameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((Display_Width, Display_Height))
            pygame.display.set_caption("Yahtzee")
            Background = pygame.image.load('Red Background.jpg')

            Dice   = pygame.image.load('Dice_1.jpg')
            Dice_1 = pygame.image.load('Dice_1.jpg')
            Dice_2 = pygame.image.load('Dice_2.jpg')
            Dice_3 = pygame.image.load('Dice_3.jpg')
            Dice_4 = pygame.image.load('Dice_4.jpg')
            Dice_5 = pygame.image.load('Dice_5.jpg')
            Dice_6 = pygame.image.load('Dice_6.jpg')
            #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("cambria", 17)
            GameDisplay.blit(Background,(0,0))
            RollsRem = 3
            count = 0
            dicexy = [[25,100], [175,100], [325,100], [475,100], [625,100]]
            #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
            randomnumber = 1
            def diceroll():
                randomnumber = random.randint(1,6)
                if randomnumber == 1:
                    Dice = Dice_1
                elif randomnumber == 2:
                    Dice = Dice_2
                elif randomnumber == 3:
                    Dice = Dice_3
                elif randomnumber == 4:
                    Dice = Dice_4
                elif randomnumber == 5:
                    Dice = Dice_5
                elif randomnumber == 6:
                    Dice = Dice_6
                print(randomnumber)

            GameQuit = False
            while not GameQuit:
                while count < 12:
                    GameDisplay.blit(Background,(0,0))
                    if RollsRem < 0:
                        count = count + 1
                        RollsRem = 3
                    for i in range(5):
                        GameDisplay.blit(Dice, dicexy[i])

                    Rolls_Remaining = myfont.render("Rolls Remaining: " + str(RollsRem), 1, (255,255,255))
                    GameDisplay.blit(Rolls_Remaining, (575, 20))
                    for event in pygame.event.get():
                        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                            GameQuit = True     
                        if RollsRem >= 0:
                            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                                    RollsRem = RollsRem -1

                                    pygame.display.update()
                                    for i in range(5):
                                        diceroll()
                                        pygame.display.update()
                                        GameDisplay.blit(Dice, dicexy[i])

                    fpsClock.tick(FPS)                
                    pygame.display.update()

            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: `Dice` in function `diceroll` has nothing to do with the `Dice` you use elswhere. You have to `return` that value from the function to the caller. BTW, please read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: btw: learn how to use list and keep images on list. You will no need so many `if/else` - you will need only one line `Dice = dice_images[randomnumber]`

Answer (score 2):

In function `diceroll()`, the variable `Dice` is treated as a local variable by the Python interpreter. Technically, you could fix that by declaring he variable `global` at the start of the function, however that would not be a good coding style.

A better option would be to return the image from that function:

```
def diceroll():
    randomnumber = random.randint(1,6)
    if randomnumber == 1:
        dice = Dice_1
    elif randomnumber == 2:
        ...
    return dice
```

And then use the result in the main loop:

```
for i in range(5):
    dice = diceroll()
    pygame.display.update()
    GameDisplay.blit(dice, dicexy[i])
```

Also, consider using an array for storing the dice images. In that way you can access the right image based on a random index without the cumbersome `if ... elif ... else` block.